# Summary sheet based on filters/tags

Tags: excel

I have a table that shows information about hardware (things like price, manufacturer, etc). I have created a summary sheet that does things like showing the total cost of buying everything new, etc. I want to be able to filter this information though so that it does not always show the total cost of everything.

**For Example**

*H/W table*

```
| Type | Manufacturer | Price | Priority | End Of Life |
|      |              |       |          |             |
```

*Summary*

```
| Type |  Cost1 | Cost2 | Total |             | Priority | Y/N |
|  X   |    -   |   -   |   -   |             |   High   |  Y  |
|  Y   |    -   |   -   |   -   |             |  Medium  |  N  |
|  Z   |    -   |   -   |   -   |             |   Low    |  N  |
|      |    |Grand Total|   -   |
```

So the aim is to be able to say "only show the high priority kit", for example, and the summary would reflect only the kit marked with a high priority. Currently I have a separate little table with each of the priority levels in it, the user has to mark each row in that table with a Y or N to show if they want to see those priorities in the cost. I then have a column in the original table that only shows the price if the priority marked is in the list with Y next to them. The summary is then based on this price column instead of the actual price column.

It works, but from a programming background, it feels scrappy and hacky. It also relies on the columns being the same, so the summary sheet mucks up if we add a column.

My question is: Is there an easy way to filter the data shown in the summary sheet?

**Note**

I know that pivot tables exist but I have yet to get them working with this data set, but would also like to get this working without using pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you use

- filter for priority (the auto filter I mean).
- Use not the SUM() function, but use SUBTOTAL() function. In subtotal you can ask a total only for visible values.

If you filter to "high" priority, you can see the sum of high priority.
Of course you can leave the SUM() as well, you you can immediate see the total and the "high" priority data, even you can calculate the percentage of "high" priority over sum total.

OR

You can use SUMIF function and enter somewhere the filter as "High" "Medium" etc. This also works nicely.

Entering data in 2 sheets is risky and tedious.